# Getting the total of multiple functions outputs in Javascript, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function called `numFunc()`, which produces a numeric output.
I want to run this function 5 times and get the sum of all 5 outputs.

Here's what I've tried

```
function total(){
for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) //run the function 5 times
{
  var numF = numFunc(); //store the output from the function in a variable
  var sum = sum+numF; //Get the sum of all 5 variables
}
console.log(sum);

}
total();
```

But, what I get is the following output

```
3
3
3
3
3
NaN
```

What I want is the sum as a single value. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Declare the variable `sum` outside of the `for`. **Code:** `function total() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (itr = 1; itr <= 5; itr++) {
        sum += numFunc();
    }
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
}
total();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variabble outside of the loop and set it to a number value otherwise you are adding an undefined to an integer. Thanks @jfriend00 for the clarification

```
function total(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) //run the function 5 times
    {
      var numF = numFunc(); //store the output from the function in a variable
      sum = sum + numF; //Get the sum of all 5 variables
    }
    console.log(sum);

}
total();
```

Comment: The issue is that the `sum` was never initialized to zero before the `for` loop so `sum+numF` doesn't work when `sum` is not initialized first.  Your solution will work, but the explanation for why is not really correct.  FYI, the actual `var sum` is hoisted to the top of the function automatically.

Comment: Try logging the return of numFunc()

Answer (score 0):

In the statement:

```
var sum = sum + numF;
```

You are trying to add something that does not yet exist, because you just declared it there with the `var`

With your statement, you should be declaring the vars above the loop:

```
function total(){
    // declaring the variables before you use them.
    // I will set them to 0 so I know they're supposed to be numbers, and 0 wont affect the outcome of the function
    var numF = 0;
    var sum = 0;        

    for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++) //run the function 5 times
    {
      numF = numFunc(); //store the output from the function in a variable
      sum = sum+numF; //Get the sum of all 5 variables
    }
    console.log(sum);

}
total();
```

Comment: So I tried it like this as advised by most of you guys.

Comment: function total(){
    var sum = 0;
    var numF = 0;
    for (itr=1; itr<=5; itr++)
    {
      numF = numFunc(); 
      sum = sum + numF; 
    }
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
}
total();

Comment: But I still get the same result

Comment: This code works. What does your numFunc() look like?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying an array, and then adding that array values externally after the function fires like this?

EDIT: Used the repl.it code editor to test this theory out.  I had to change the code a bit but remained under the same premise. Used separate the functions and then fed the array builder function into the calculator function to properly calculate the array variables.  Repl link here: (https://repl.it/B128/1)

```
function numFunc(){
    return 3;
};

function total(){
    var toBeSummed = []; //set up an array to put your sum variables into as a more versatile variable type to perform this in.
    for (var itr=0; itr<5; itr++){ //runs the function 5 times 
        var numF = numFunc(); //store the output from the function
        var arrayItr = itr; //uses "itr" variable to iterate a 0 based index 5 times
        toBeSummed[arrayItr] = numF; //for each arrayItr 0-5 makes the array value equal to the numF value.
    };
    return toBeSummed;
};

var sum = 0;

function counter(totals){
    for(sums in totals){ //iterates the x array elements(5 in this case)
        sum = sum + totals[sums]; // Adds the current value of sum, plus the values at each existing array point(at this point values in array index 0-5)
        //console.log(sum); //Should now log the correct set of sums "browser" 
    };
    console.log(sum);
};


counter(total());
```

Comment: Also, to make it a bit more robust, I'd change "for (var itr=1; itr<=5; itr++){ "  to "for (var itr=1; itr<=[varNameYouSet.length]; itr++){ " which should allow you to go even further into reusable code, and allow you to set a variable for the amount of times you want to run this, whether it's 1, 5, or 50 with the same code I provided you.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but don't you think that line (7): 'toBeSummed[arrayItr] = numF; for each arrayItr 0-5 makes the array value equal to the numF value' should be commented somewhere :)

Comment: Created repetitive "numFunc" to just return a number "x" times. "total" function constructs an array from your function. "counter" function (bad naming on my part I know) consumes the array "toBeSummed" and the for-in loop sums "x" numbers.  So now, if you were to change your original FOR loop from "itr<5" to "itr<variable.length" you can control that variable by the length of the object you pass with your "numFunc" and iterate ANY count of numbers using this code.  If you want to see it work number by number uncomment "//console.log(sum);"  in counter function and it'll show you each sum.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. 
I think I found the issue. The original numFunc() function seemed to have a console.log() statement that's why I kept on getting the list of 3's all the time, replacing that with a return resolved that.

And as you guys suggested declaring the sum variable outside the loop prevented the display of 'NaN'